# <button type="button"> used as form value on submit

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure the "best" method of having a button `type=button` show up on the form submit. These are not submit buttons, but they do fire some js for calculations but I also need their name and value to be posted.

I think I can also have a checkbox of the same name and jquery update this checked status, but that seems unprofessional and I would also have to hide the checkboxes.

**Is there a elegant solution for this?**

Using Twitter Bootstrap, jquery, Ruby on Rails.

The main goal of this approach is to have a few big buttons as checkboxes for easy use on a tablet etc.

Comment: Why not use `<input type="button" name="theButton" value="Click me"/>`?

Comment: I have tried that too. without results.... I should probably add that I really only want the value be posted if the button is in an active state. But I can get that from the js

Comment: So is the issue, then, that you want the button value submitted even though the button is not doing the form submit? The only solution I can think of is to mirror the value of the button in a hidden input field. You could do it as part of the form's submit event. This doesn't meet the definition of 'elegant' :-\, but it would work.

Comment: What do you mean "button is in an active state"? The only button in an active state, as far as the HTML spec is concerned, is the one being used to submit the form.

Comment: The active state is refering to how twitter bootstrap specific conditions of the button.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ajax to serve your purpose. In the view you just have a button with text box, enter some input and click on the button.   IN Jquery onclick method is called and the value is passed as ajax and your calculations can be carried upon and the result is stored in the db(if required).

Your view code should be something like this

```
<input type="button" id="submitt">
<div id="myDiv"> </div>
```

Your jquery code should be like this

```
 var content = '';
$(document).ready(function() {  
 $('#submitt').click(function(){


// do some calculations and store it in a variable nm
        $.ajax({url:"demo/"+nm, success:function(result){         
           myFunction(result);
           $("#myDiv").html(content);  // To output the result           
       }});
        return false;
});
});

    function myFunction(result)
{
             content = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                content += result[i].name;
                content += '<br/>';
            }
}
```

In the routing file

```
match 'demo/:nm' => 'demo#newsy'
```

and finally in the controller file

```
def newsy
    @name = request["nm"]  
    new_emp = Client.new
    new_emp.name = @name
    new_emp.save
    @myys = Client.all
    render :json => @myys
end
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there is nothing unprofessional in hiding inputs. And if you don't want to hide checkboxes, you can use `type="hidden"`

Working [demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/X5Gmy/)

```html
<button type="button" data-name="myName" class="btn" data-toggle="btn-input" data-target="#myButtonState" value="myValue">Click me</button>
<input type="hidden" id="myButtonState" />
```

```js
$('[data-toggle="btn-input"]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $input = $($this.data('target'));
    var name = $this.data('name');
    var active = false;                  // Maybe check button state instead
    $this.on('click',function() {
        active = !active;

        if(active) $input.attr('name', name).val($this.val());
        else       $input.removeAttr('name');

        $this.button('toggle');
    });
});
```

The `removeAttr` mimics the checkbox state (whether it's submitted or not).

Comment: Im pretty sure this is the method ill use. I think it will work for me.