# jQuery + Bootstrap, checkbox button group & select multiple input, submit to form

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Here's the html code:

```
<Div>
    <Div ‪#‎btn‬-group>
        <button value=0><img />Foo</button>
        <button value=1 class=active><img />Lor</button>
        <button value=2 class=active><img />Bar</button>
        <button value=3><img />Ips</button>
    </div>
    <select hidden multiple>
        <option value=0>
        <option value=1 selected>
        <option value=2 selected>
        <option value=3>
    </select>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n6ns4/5/

I dont want it to constantly be running. So I have been trying to call .on() and .click() and .trigger() on the buttons. Which would then if check for "active", then add a selected, else remove selected. But the buttons dont toggle to ".active" until after the click/on/trigger completes.

I dont care what you change, but the requirements:

- button needs to contain dynamic image and text (which is why i'm not
  using checkbox.)
- and the result needs to be able to submit to a form.

eventually it's going to use php laravel for the content.

---

Basically, if a button is pressed on top, and has the class 'active'...

Then the corresponding select option should have the attribute 'selected'

---

Or... Simply a way to submit a group of separated, toggling buttons with a dynamic image on them, to a form.

Comment: I believe you have a bug in your first div, the #btn-group should just be id="btn-group" if that is supposed to be your css selector.

Comment: I was trying to make it kind of short hand for concept. The code is valid in real life: http://jsfiddle.net/n6ns4/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the method described here, trying to use select was a poor decision. answer source:

- [<button type="button"> used as form value on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750865/button-type-button-used-as-form-value-on-submit)

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nQFxU/3/

**code**

*HTML*

```
<div id="btn-group">
  <button type="button" data-name="uid0" class="btn" data-toggle="btn-input" data-target="#puBtn0" value="uid0">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50">
    <br>Randy</button>
  <input type="hidden" id="puBtn0" />
  <button type="button" data-name="uid1" class="btn" data-toggle="btn-input" data-target="#puBtn1" value="uid1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50">
    <br>Dick</button>
  <input type="hidden" id="puBtn1" />
  <button type="button" data-name="uid2" class="btn" data-toggle="btn-input" data-target="#puBtn2" value="uid2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50">
    <br>Jane</button>
  <input type="hidden" id="puBtn2" />
  <button type="button" data-name="uid3" class="btn" data-toggle="btn-input" data-target="#puBtn3" value="uid3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50">
    <br>Alice</button>
  <input type="hidden" id="puBtn3" />
  <button type="button" data-name="uid4" class="btn" data-toggle="btn-input" data-target="#puBtn4" value="uid4">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50">
    <br>John</button>
  <input type="hidden" id="puBtn4" />
</div>
```

*JS*

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('[data-toggle="btn-input"]').each(function () {
         var $this = $(this);
         var $input = $($this.data('target'));
         var name = $this.data('name');
         var active = false; // Maybe check button state instead
         $this.on('click', function () {
             active = !active;

             if (active) $input.attr('name', name).val($this.val());
             else $input.removeAttr('name').removeAttr('value');

             $this.button('toggle');
         });
     });
 });
```

*conclusion*

This works, it's a lot less hassle, and it's just as easy to put into effect. The downside to this is in my form submit result I have `.html?ID1=ID1&ID2=ID2` when I was hoping for `.html?users=ID1+ID2+ID3`

Answer (score 0):

So, something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6ns4/10/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('div.partnerBtnGroup button').on('click', function (ev) {
         var btn = $(this).toggleClass('active');
         var uid = btn.prop("value");
         $("select option[value='" + uid + "']").prop('selected', btn.hasClass('active'));
         $('pre').html(JSON.stringify($('#partnersSelect').val()));
         ev.stopPropagation();
     });
 });
```

Comment: This one selects the option in the gui, but doesnt change the DOM (yet).

Also the deselecting didnt work. I dont think "selected", false actually stops it.

Comment: Do you need it to update the DOM or just what will be sent to the server? I added a `<pre>` tag that shows the value of the select on each click. And adding `stopPropagation` makes it deselect.

Answer (score 0):

oh I like that answer Kalley, this is what I got.

```
<script>
$(function() {

        $("#btn‬Group button").click(function(){
            var $thisButton = $('#btnGrouSelect option[value'+$(this).attr('value')+']');
            if($(this).hasClass('active')){
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                if($thisButton.is(':selected')){} else {$thisButton.prop("selected", false)}
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('active');
                if($thisButton.is(':selected')){} else { $thisButton.prop("selected", true)}
            }

            //$thisValue = $(this).attr('value');
        })  

});
// BEGIN: jQuery functions on load
</script>



<Div>
<Div id="btn‬Group">
    <button value=0>[img0] 0</button>
    <button value=1>[img1] 1</button>
    <button value=2>[img2] 2</button>
    <button value=3>[img3] 3</button>
</div>
    <select multiple id="btnGrouSelect">
        <option value=0>0</option>
        <option value=1>1</option>
        <option value=2>2</option>
        <option value=3>3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</div>
```